# Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' for some input

Tags: python

I am doing some homework and in the following code option four encounters an error (Python 3.5).

> > can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

```
def main():
    costpp = 20.00
    numberOfPeople = input("How many people are coming to wedding?")
    print("Please select a number for your choice:")
    print("1) Print the invitee list")
    print("2) Print the menu")
    print("3) Print the text of the invitation")
    print("4) Print your cost")
    choice = input()
    if choice == "1":
        printInviteeList()
    if choice == "2":
        printMenu()
    if choice == "3":
        print("You are invited to the wedding")
    if choice == "4":
        printCost  (numberOfPeople,   costpp)

def printInviteeList(): 
    print("Mia, Olga,   Sahar,    Rcheal, Ding, Gary, Jenny,    Lian,    Quan, Jack")

def printMenu():
    print("Beef, Lamb, Bread, Egg, Crab, Cake")

def printCost(numberOfPeople, costPerPerson):       
    totalcost = numberOfPeople*costPerPerson
    return totalcost

main()
```

Comment: `numberOfPeople` is a string, you need to cast it to an int. E.g. `numberOfPeople = int(input("How many people are coming to wedding?"))`

Comment: @TomDalton You should make this an answer.

Answer (score 3):

`input()` returns a string so after this line:

```
numberOfPeople = input("How many people are coming to wedding?")
```

`numberOfPeople` will be a string. Say you entered `100`, `numberOfPeople` will then be the string `'100'`.

It is not valid to multiply a string by a floating point number - it makes no sense:

```
>>> numberOfPeople * 2.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

To fix this, convert `numberOfPeople` into a numeric type, an `int` in this case, using `int()`:

```
numberOfPeople = int(input("How many people are coming to wedding?"))

>>> numberOfPeople * 2.0
200.0
```

It is interesting to note that it is valid to multiply a string by an `int`:

```
>>> '100' * 2
'100100'
```

which concatenates the string *n* times, in this case 2.

Comment: It is not wise simply to convert a string to an int (especially when the string is created by user input).  You should use a `try` block.  I am not suggesting an edit to your answer; there are too many options to be covered by a simple answer, but I do merely comment.